# How to concatenate date and time in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, datetime, join

I have a list which looks like this:

```
my_list = 
[['BCN', '01-01-2021', '08:30:30'],
 ['MCR', '01-01-2021', '12:48:12'],
 ['TNG', '01-01-2021', '10:01:02']]
```

For every list in `my_list` iam trying to join `index[1]` + `index[2]` and write it back in a new list.

**This is my code:**

```
new_list = []
for row in my_list:
    ' '.join(row[1] + row[2])
    new_list.append(row)

print(new_list)
```

****This is my output:****

```
[['BCN', '01-01-2021', '08:30:30'],
 ['MCR', '01-01-2021', '12:48:12'], 
 ['TNG', '01-01-2021', '10:01:02']]
```

**This is my expected output:**

```
[['BCN', '01-01-2021 08:30:30'], 
 ['MCR', '01-01-2021 12:48:12'], 
 ['TNG', '01-01-2021 10:01:02']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just adding the last two elements of each row, not assigning it anywhere. Try this:

```
new_list = []
for row in my_list:
    new_list.append([row[0], ' '.join(row[1:])])

print(new_list)
# Output
# [['BCN', '01-01-2021 08:30:30'], 
#  ['MCR', '01-01-2021 12:48:12'], 
#  ['TNG', '01-01-2021 10:01:02']]
```

A shorter version would be:

```
>>> [[first, ' '.join(rest)] for first, *rest in my_list]

[['BCN', '01-01-2021 08:30:30'],
 ['MCR', '01-01-2021 12:48:12'],
 ['TNG', '01-01-2021 10:01:02']]
```

**EDIT:**

```
>>> my_list

[['BCN', '01-01-2021', '08:30:30', 'other0'],
 ['MCR', '01-01-2021', '12:48:12', 'other1'],
 ['TNG', '01-01-2021', '10:01:02', 'other2']]

>>> new_list = []
>>> for row in my_list:
...     new_list.append([row[0], ' '.join(row[1:3]), row[-1]])

>>> new_list
[['BCN', '01-01-2021 08:30:30', 'other0'],
 ['MCR', '01-01-2021 12:48:12', 'other1'],
 ['TNG', '01-01-2021 10:01:02', 'other2']]
```

Or,

```
>>> [[first, ' '.join(rest), last] for first, *rest, last in my_list]

[['BCN', '01-01-2021 08:30:30', 'other0'],
 ['MCR', '01-01-2021 12:48:12', 'other1'],
 ['TNG', '01-01-2021 10:01:02', 'other2']]
```

For even more items:

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> for row in my_list:
...     new_list.append([row[0], ' '.join(row[1:3]), *row[3:]])
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the one in the for loop :)

Comment: So what if I had an other object in the list behind the time?

Comment: For the first approach, change `row[1:]` to `row[1:3]`, for the second approach change `first, *rest` to `first, *rest, other`

Comment: but I dont want the last object to be joined with date and time.

Comment: It won't join the last object.

Comment: @Try it out, add a new object to every list and then do it. Nothing will change.

Comment: Oke thank you. What if I had more then 1 items in the back?

Comment: @TangerCity added.

Answer (score 1):

There is no assignment in this line and it doesn't do what you expect, because it first appends the strings (+) and then places a space between each character (join):

```
    ' '.join(row[1] + row[2])
```

This does what you're trying to do:

```
for row in my_list:
    new_list.append(row[0])
    new_list.append(row[1] + ' ' + row[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't change the value of row

Try:

```
for row in my_list:
    row = [row[0], ' '.join([row[1], row[2]])]
    new_list.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two things you have to consider to fix

1. You did not assign the new formatted value to any var
2. `+` in ' '.join(row[1] + row[2]) first appends then joins

You can fix 2nd issue like

> 1. `' '.join([row[1], row[2]])`
> 2. `' '.join(row[1:])`
> 3. `row[1] + " " + row[2]`

**So the solution can be like --**

```
# Your list
my_list = [['BCN', '01-01-2021', '08:30:30'],
 ['MCR', '01-01-2021', '12:48:12'],
 ['TNG', '01-01-2021', '10:01:02']]
 
# Newly formatted list
new_list = []
for row in my_list:
    # You have to change these two lines - assign new formatted value to a var and append that into your new_list
    changed = [row[0], row[1] + " " + row[2]]
    new_list.append(changed)

print(new_list)
```